# Stack overflow exception with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a WPF application that is uses Entity Framework. In the model I have 2 classes, one called Category and one called Group.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public List<Part> Parts{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I have created Wrappers for both classes.

```
    public partial class CategoryWrapper:ModelWrapper<Category>
{
    public CategoryWrapper(Category model) : base(model)
    {
        InitializeCollectionProperties(model);
    }


    public System.Int32 Id
    {
      get{return GetValue<System.Int32>();}
      set{SetValue(value);}
    }   
    public System.Int32 IdOriginalValue => GetOriginalValue<System.Int32>(nameof(Id));
    public bool IdHasChanged => GetIsChanged(nameof(Id));



    public System.String Name
    {
      get{return GetValue<System.String>();}
      set{SetValue(value);}
    }   
    public System.String NameOriginalValue => GetOriginalValue<System.String>(nameof(Name));
    public bool NameHasChanged => GetIsChanged(nameof(Name));


    public ChangeTrackingCollection<GroupWrapper> Groups { get; set; }
    public override void InitializeCollectionProperties(Category model)
    {

        if (model.Groups ==null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Groups = new ChangeTrackingCollection<GroupWrapper>(
            model.Groups.Select(x => new GroupWrapper(x)));
        RegisterCollection(Groups,model.Groups);

    }

}
public partial class GroupWrapper:ModelWrapper<Group>
{
    public GroupWrapper(Group model) : base(model)
    {
        InitializeCollectionProperties(model);
        InitializeComplexProperties(model);
    }


    public System.Int32 Id
    {
      get{return GetValue<System.Int32>();}
      set{SetValue(value);}
    }   
    public System.Int32 IdOriginalValue => GetOriginalValue<System.Int32>(nameof(Id));
    public bool IdHasChanged => GetIsChanged(nameof(Id));



    public System.String Name
    {
      get{return GetValue<System.String>();}
      set{SetValue(value);}
    }   
    public System.String NameOriginalValue => GetOriginalValue<System.String>(nameof(Name));
    public bool NameHasChanged => GetIsChanged(nameof(Name));



    public System.Int32 CategoryId
    {
      get{return GetValue<System.Int32>();}
      set{SetValue(value);}
    }   
    public System.Int32 CategoryIdOriginalValue => GetOriginalValue<System.Int32>(nameof(CategoryId));
    public bool CategoryIdHasChanged => GetIsChanged(nameof(CategoryId));


    public CategoryWrapper Category { get; private set; }
    public ChangeTrackingCollection<PartWrapper> Parts { get; set; }
    public override void InitializeComplexProperties(Group model)
    {

        if (model.Category ==null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Category = new CategoryWrapper(model.Category);
        RegisterComplex(Category);

    }
    public override void InitializeCollectionProperties(Group model)
    {

        if (model.Parts ==null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Parts = new ChangeTrackingCollection<PartWrapper>(
            model.Parts.Select(x => new PartWrapper(x)));
        RegisterCollection(Parts,model.Parts);

    }

}
```

Then I have a small bit of code that calls the entity framework.

```
    public async Task<CategoryWrapper> AsyncCategory(int categoryId)
    {

        return await Task.Run(() => _selectRepository
            .Categories()
            .Where(x => x.Id == categoryId)
            .Select(x => new CategoryWrapper(x))
            .FirstOrDefault());
    }
   // here is Categories
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories()
    {
        using (var context = new ShipListContext())
        {
            return context.Categories
                .Include(x => x.Groups)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

This piece of code is where I am getting my exception. I am not sure why because when i run my tests I do not get my errors. I have split the query into the same query just 3 lines and I have noticed that in the quick watch window I look at Category.Groups there are 10 Groups and each Group there is a Group.Category with a Category.Groups inside that. So, How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Use the debugger and carefully inspect the stack trace when the exception occurs.

Comment: In the `CategoryWrapper` constructor you call `InitializeCollectionProperties`, which calls `new CategoryWrapper(...)` again. You simply have a circular reference.

Comment: I have found the issue it is with the GroupWrapper InitializeComplexProperty I call a new Category.